# why does it tell me IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, reinforcement-learning

In the following code for reinforcement learning, when I run it on google colabs I don't get the error, but on Jupiter Notebooks I get:

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices.
What should be changed?

```
import numpy as np
import gym


# Define the environment
env = gym.make("Taxi-v3").env

# Initialize the q-table with zero values
q_table = np.zeros([env.observation_space.n, env.action_space.n])

# Hyperparameters
alpha = 0.1  # learning-rate
gamma = 0.7  # discount-factor
epsilon = 0.1  # explor vs exploit

# Random generator
rng =np.random.default_rng()

# Perform 10,000 episodes
for i in range(10_000):
    # Reset the environment and initialize total_reward
    state = env.reset()
    done = False
    total_reward = 0
    
    # Loop as long as the game is not over, i.e. done is not True
    while not done:
        if rng.random() < epsilon:
            action = env.action_space.sample() # Explore the action space
        else:
            action = np.argmax(q_table[state]) # Exploit learned values

        # Apply the action and see what happens
        next_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action) 
        
        current_value = q_table[state, action]  # current Q-value for the state/action couple
        next_max = np.max(q_table[next_state])  # next best Q-value
        
        # Compute the new Q-value with the Bellman equation
        q_table[state, action] = (1 - alpha) * current_value + alpha * (reward + gamma * next_max)
        
        # Update the current state and total_reward
        state = next_state
        total_reward += reward
        
    # Print the total reward earned in this episode
    print(f"Episode {i+1}: Total reward = {total_reward}")
```

Comment: Please post  whole stacktrace and mark the offensive line in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `state = env.reset()`, use `state = env.reset()[0]`. This will solve your issue.